# create model method returns an integer in Laravel

Tags: laravel, methods, model, laravel-8

how to create a method inside a model in Laravel 8 that returns an integer not a relation instance ? or there is another way to do this N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App\Models\Model:

```
public function getInteger(): int
{
    //return model field as integer
    return $this->field;
}
```

Now you can call this function globaly:

```
$model->getInteger();
```

If you would like to have a method, which returns, for example, a constant value, you can do something like this:

App\Models\Model:

```
public static function getConstInteger(): int
{
    return 1;
}
```

And now you can call it globaly like this:

```
Model::getConstInteger();
```

I would strongly advise you to read the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent